# Call event and observer on Customer login in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to update customer cart on login.I have created an observer in folder 
local/goodahead/customer/etc/cofig.xml

```
<customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <updatelogincart_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>goodahead_customer/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </updatelogincart_observer>
                </observers>
        </customer_login>
```

and in Observer at path local/goodahead/customer/Model/Observer.php ,i have created the function customerLogin

```
class Goodahead_Customer_Model_Observer
{
public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        mail('muemailaddress@gmail.com','hello','test');
    }
}
```

But i am not getting any mail.

How can i do this?

Comment: you want add products to cart automatically when customer logged in

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using an email to test if your observer works? That seems so incredibly error-prone, it's almost insane. If you don't have a debugger or something, at least use something simple like *die('IT WORKS!');* to see if your Observer is called, it's really impossible to miss.

Secondly, did you properly configure your model in the config.xml?

Comment: I have tried Mage log also but no file created in log folder.Can you please tell what else I have to add in config file?